# Trying to reduce repetition of HTML code using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

Hello I have been working on a project lately where I have a slider with various elements in it and when clicking on the button 'Learn more' on a particular slider element will open a pop-up modal contain specific details to that selected slider element. Now my slider is becoming really long and I am having numerous slides and modal. The only element that is shared between my slide and modal are the title and the image location and I have been wondering if I can use either JavaScript or anything to make my code look nice and remove the repeating pattern of my code Below is my code:

```
<!-- Slides 1 -->
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card_image">
            <img src="CSS/Assets/Images/Slider_Images/Teamwork.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card_info">
            <h3 class="card_title">1. Teamwork</h3>
            <p>
                The ability to work well in a team. This shows that you have the maturity to realise that no work is standalone
            </p>
            <button data-modal-target="#modal1" class="card_btn">
                <h4>Learn More</h4>
            </button>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
                                    
<!-- Slides 2 -->
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card_image">
            <img src="CSS/Assets/Images/Slider_Images/Decision Making.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="card_info">
            <h3 class="card_title">2. Decision Making</h3>
            <p>
                Decision making is the process of making choices by identifying a decision, and assessing alternative resolutions. 
            </p>
            <button data-modal-target="#modal2" class="card_btn">
                <h4>Learn More</h4>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my code I have numerous slides and when clicking on the button Learn More should open another code which repeat itself as follows:

```
<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
    <div class="modal_header">
        <div class="modal_image">
            <img src="CSS/Assets/Images/Slider_Images/Teamwork.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_body">
        <h3 class="modal_title">1. Teamwork</h3>
        <div class="modal_para">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga assumenda nulla reprehenderit. Numquam culpa, quidem pariatur nam commodi ea necessitatibus incidunt sunt sapiente laboriosam asperiores assumenda repudiandae? Perspiciatis, sed! Veniam?
            </p>
        </div>
        <button data-close-button class="close-button">Close</button>
    </div>   
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal" id="modal2">
    <div class="modal_header">
        <div class="modal_image">
            <img src="CSS/Assets/Images/Slider_Images/Decision Making.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_body">
        <h3 class="modal_title">2. Decision Making</h3>
        <div class="modal_para">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fuga assumenda nulla reprehenderit. Numquam culpa, quidem pariatur nam commodi ea necessitatibus incidunt sunt sapiente laboriosam asperiores assumenda repudiandae? Perspiciatis, sed! Veniam?
            </p>
        </div>
        <button data-close-button class="close-button">Close</button>
    </div>   
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

My question for that is: Is there a way for me to continue add other slides and modal in a way that would reduce the repeated HTML pattern in JavaScript or PHP while keeping the integrity of my code ? Each element in the slider are different a open a respective modal pop-up they only share the same image location and title. The text however is not shared between the slide and modal and I was wondering if any code in JavaScript will help me having a cleaner code as my project slider is increasing

Comment: It's called a loop. What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can loop through array of your data using php, or use ReactJS to do that using js

Comment: at the moment not much ive been trying to populate it using a single slider and modal with id with no luck im still new to that can you help

Comment: are using php or just html?

Comment: im using php and javaScript

Comment: Why don't you use component-based libraries like ReactJS? It solves this problem for you.

Comment: based on my project I cannot use component-based libraries :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using php you can just use an array of arrays and loop through it to create your slides:

```
<?php
     $myslides = array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'title' => 'First slide',
                'content' => 'somthing to say',
                'imgUrl' => 'http://myimageslink.com/img.png'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'title' => 'Second slide',
                'content' => 'somthing to say',
                'imgUrl' => 'http://myimageslink.com/img.png'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 3,
                'title' => 'third slide',
                'content' => 'somthing to say',
                'imgUrl' => 'http://myimageslink.com/img.png'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 4,
                'title' => 'Fourth slide',
                'content' => 'somthing to say',
                'imgUrl' => 'http://myimageslink.com/img.png'
            ),
            //More arrays means more slides
    );

?>
```

then loop array to get your slides :

```
 <?php
    
        foreach($myslides as $slide) :
    ?>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_image">
                <img src="<?= $slide['imgUrl']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="card_info">
                <h3 class="card_title"><?= $slide['title']; ?></h3>
                <p>
                    <?= $slide['content']; ?>
                </p>
                <button data-modal-target="#modal<?= $slide['id']; ?>" class="card_btn">
                    <h4>Learn More</h4>
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php 
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

and don't forget to loop also through your model
the same loop with different html

```
<?php
    
        foreach($myslides as $slide) :
    ?>

    <div class="modal" id="modal<?= $slide['id']; ?>">
        <div class="modal_header">
            <div class="modal_image">
                <img src="<?= $slide['imgUrl']; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal_body">
            <h3 class="modal_title"><?= $slide['title']; ?></h3>
            <div class="modal_para">
                <p>
                    <?= $slide['content']; ?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <button data-close-button class="close-button">Close</button>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>

    <?php 
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

**PS:** Php is good for rendrering html, but better keep it for other server side tasks, you may consider learning ReactJS to handle complicated frontEnd tasks